# Como extraer datos de MySQL de JSON iterando

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL en la cual tengo almacenada una cantidad considerable de respuestas que siguen una misma estructura en JSON, mediante una sentencia SQL he intentado extraer los datos de tal modo que sea puedan llevar a Excel.

Esta es la estructura de un registro:

```
{
"codConsulta": "000000000000",
"codRespuesta": "01",
"observaciones": "Consulta Exitosa.",
"respuesta": {
    "datosBasicos": {
        "edad": 52,
        "genero": "M",
        "nombre": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "numeroId": "000000000000000000",
        "tipoId": "CC"
    },
    "detalladoEmpleos": [
        {
            "direccionEmpleador": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "id": 1,
            "identifiacionEmpleador": "000000000000000000",
            "nombreEmpleador": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "pagos": [
                {
                    "diasCotizados": 9,
                    "fechaPago": "2002-07-11 00:00:00",
                    "ibc": 1046268,
                    "id": 1,
                    "periodo": "200206",
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 104626
                },
                {
                    "diasCotizados": 30,
                    "fechaPago": "2002-06-14 00:00:00",
                    "ibc": 1046268,
                    "id": 2,
                    "periodo": "200205",
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 104623
                }
            ],
            "telefonoEmpleador": "0000000",
            "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI"
        },
        {
            "direccionEmpleador": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "id": 1,
            "identifiacionEmpleador": "000000000000000000",
            "nombreEmpleador": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "pagos": [
                {
                    "diasCotizados": 9,
                    "fechaPago": "2002-07-11 00:00:00",
                    "ibc": 1046268,
                    "id": 1,
                    "periodo": "200206",
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 104626
                },
                {
                    "diasCotizados": 30,
                    "fechaPago": "2002-06-14 00:00:00",
                    "ibc": 1046268,
                    "id": 2,
                    "periodo": "200205",
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": 104623
                }
            ],
            "telefonoEmpleador": "0000000",
            "tipoIdentifiacionEmpleador": "NI"
        }
    ],
    "fechaVinculacion": "1996-10-01 00:00:00"
}
```

}

El array "detalladoEmpleos" como lo imaginann pueden tener hasta n empleos y cada empleo puede tener una cantidad n de pagos en su array "pagos"

Como mencioné he tratado con una sentencia SQL pero lamentablemente no tengo la suficiente experiencia, agradecería de su ayuda.

Agrego la sentencia SQL, esta recoje los datos extraidos del JSON hasta el objeto con el array mas externo, pero pasandole un indice estatico (la primera posición [0]):

```
SELECT 
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.codConsulta' as codigoConsulta,
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.datosBasicos.nombre' as nombre,
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.datosBasicos.edad' as edad,
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.datosBasicos.genero' as genero,
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.datosBasicos.tipoId' as tipoId,
BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA->>'$.respuesta.datosBasicos.numeroId' as id,
-- json_extract(BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA,'$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos') as empleos,
json_extract(BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA,CONCAT( '$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos','[',0, '].id')) as idEmpleo,
json_extract(BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA,CONCAT( '$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos','[',0, '].identifiacionEmpleador')) as idEmpleo,
json_extract(BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA,CONCAT( '$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos','[',0, '].nombreEmpleador')) as idEmpleo,
json_extract(BITCONSULTA_DATOS_RESPUESTA,CONCAT( '$.respuesta.detalladoEmpleos','[',0, '].pagos')) as idEmpleo
FROM AG_BITCONSULTA
where BITCONSULTA_CODIGO 
and BITCONSULTA_FECHA_INICIAL between '2021-09-15 00:00:00' and '2021-10-01 00:00:00';
```

Aqui una foto de la salidad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reitero, el problema que tengo es que no se como iterar con los dos array que exiten, el array de empleos y el array de pagos por cada empleo.

Nuevamente gracias

Comment: Buenas tardes, qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Lo estas intentado hacer desde Mysql? O con algún lenguaje como Php, Python..?

Comment: Buenas tardes. No estoy utilizando ningún lenguaje de programación, solo sql, lo que he intentando inicialmente es funciones de mysql como json_lenght()  para obtener el tamaño del array  más externo que es el de empleos y luego he hecho con este tamaño un While dentro del while he intentado por cada pago obtener sus datos. Otra función que he utilizado es json_extract() para extraer los datos, ahora estoy desde el móvil, cuando llegue a mi casa comparto la sentencia sql, gracias por el interés

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar hacer un Select con JSON_EXTRACT, para poder acceder a determinados valores del JSON la función de extract nos lo facilita accediendo en el siguiente orden.

Ejemplo de json :

Tabla peliculas

```
 id  | titulo    | etiquetas                                        |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | batman    | {"acerca": {"genero": "accion", "cool": true}}   |
```

SELECT titulo, JSON_EXTRACT(etiquetas, '$.acerca.genero') AS genero FROM peliculas;

resultado:

```
| titulo      | genero    |
+-------------+-----------+
| batman      | "accion"  |
+-------------+-----------+
```

De esta forma podemos acceder a los distintos niveles del json.

Comment: Hola Javier, eso lo he entendido, pero resulta que los niveles vienen dados por array, por lo cual debería acceder a estos por su índice